# Gaps in the plot of a cumulative distribution function produced from HistogramDistribution

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have about 200 real numbers spread over the range 0-400.  I use `HistogramDistribution` to bin them and `PDF` to create the resulting step-wise probability distribution. I assumed that `CDF` applied to the `HistogramDistribution` would yield a continuous, piece-wise linear function, but I keep getting these annoying gaps in the plot of the CDF.

Here's the code I'm using applied to some random data:

```
data = Table[400*RandomReal[], {200}];
pd = PDF[HistogramDistribution[data, 20]];
Plot[pd[x], {x, 0, 400}]
Plot[CDF[HistogramDistribution[data, 20], x], {x, 0, 400}]
```

Any idea what's causing the gaps and how to get rid of them?

Comment: Add `PlotPoints -> 500` to your final Plot command.

Comment: @bills `Exclusions -> None` is the better approach in this case.

Comment: If your real data displays near zero values for the histogram in the extremes of the data (as opposed to data from distributions like a uniform where the density is very non-negative at the boundaries), you might consider using `SmoothKernelDistribution` instead.  This gives you a smooth curve for the density rather than a bumpy histogram.  You can use `PDF` and `CDF` with the object produced by `SmoothKernelDistribution` just like `HistogramDistribution`.

Comment: Yet another option would be to use DiscretePlot with your CDF; `DiscretePlot[CDF[HistogramDistribution[data, 20], x], {x, 0, 400}, 
 Filling -> None, Joined -> True]` generates [this plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nisfA.png). As an aside, your data can be more efficiently generated using: `data = RandomReal[{0, 400}, 200]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is based on Brett Champion's comment. The gaps can be removed by giving the option `Exclusions -> None`.

```
SeedRandom[1]; data = RandomReal[400, 200];

Plot[PDF[HistogramDistribution[data, 20], x], {x, 0, 400}]
```

[image: pdf]

```
Plot[CDF[HistogramDistribution[data, 20], x], {x, 0, 400}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: cdf]

Answer (score 0):

The discreteness imposed by the arbitrary parameters of a Histogram seems an unnecessary  burden to me. I would do

```
ed = EmpiricalDistribution[data];

Plot[CDF[ed, x], {x, 0, 400}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with no arbitrary smoothness and discontinuities in the slope other than the one imposed by the data itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, unlike the `RandomReal[400,200]` example data, the real data has a low probability tail with significant gaps.  I thought the histogram bins would help smooth that out a bit, giving something closer to the actual smooth distribution than the extended zero regions of an `Empirical Distribution[data]`.

Comment: I guess this goes beyond the Mathematica topic, but in terms  of my scientific "ideology" I have little appreciation for parametric estimators, such as histograms, precisely because they allow artificial beautification of the data. Histograms perform the worse in tailed distributions and are only tolerable for almost normal distributions.